# How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome in MAC OS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver
>   system property; for more information, see
>   http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
>   version can be downloaded from
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:110)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:118)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:291)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:82)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:117)
>     at selenium.basics.Chrome.chromeBrowser(Chrome.java:16)     at
>   selenium.basics.Firefox.main(Firefox.java:8)

Comment: Have you tried installing the chromedriver as it suggests?

Comment: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Duplicate of  [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path) and [Selenium using Java - The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/selenium-using-java-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the latest chrome version from

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Path should be adjusted through build path.

Try it once, it is helping to you...

Answer (score 4):

user5899853 Try this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" ,  "/Users/sampada/Applications/chromedriver");
```

And:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
driver = new ChromeDriver(); //init chrome driver
driver.get("http://google.com”); //url of website we like to test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use brew to install chromedriver and keep it up-to-date:

```
brew install chromedriver
```

Comment: It's actually placed in a cask: `brew cask install chromedriver`

Comment: Just an update to the above comment, brew now disables the above command. From brew: > Error: Calling `brew cask install` is disabled! Use brew install [--cask] instead.

Answer (score 1):

**1. You can check the current chromedriver version: `chromedriver --version`**

**2. Install via command line: https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/chromedriver**

```
brew install --cask chromedriver
```

**3. Be careful if your chrome version is not the same**
https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads

**4. Add this driver to your selenium code**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Extract the chrome/firefox driver executable to Applications folder
and follow the below code.

This should work for you :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Applications/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just run the below in** **terminal**:

```
brew cask install chromedriver
```

Comment: Just an update to the above brew now disables the above command. From brew: > Error: Calling `brew cask install` is disabled! Use brew install [--cask] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a few good hours trying to get Selenium/Chrome to work on my Mac.

The obvious:

- Download the selenium driver from this location:
  https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
- Open the zip file and add client-combined-#VERSION#.jar to the included jars of your project.

What I was missing:

- Add the jars that are under the libs directory of the selenium sources you just downloaded as well.

Hope this helps