# Selenium using Java - The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am trying to launch Mozilla but still I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

I am using `Selenium 3.0.01` Beta version and `Mozilla 45`. I have tried with `Mozilla 47` too. but still the same thing.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate issue, it occurs with `selenium 3` and it's a new issue, stacktrace is also different. Thanks..:)

Comment: You need geckodriver to launch selenium 3 tests in Firefox

Answer (score 102, accepted):

*The `Selenium` client bindings will try to locate the `geckodriver` executable from the system `PATH`. You will need to add the directory containing the executable to the system path.*

- On **Unix** systems you can do the following to append it to your system’s search path, if you’re using a bash-compatible shell:

  ```
  export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver
  ```
- On **Windows** you need to update the Path system variable to add the full directory path to the executable. The principle is the same as on Unix.

**All below configuration for launching latest firefox using any programming language binding is applicable for `Selenium2` to enable Marionette explicitly. With Selenium 3.0 and later, you shouldn't need to do anything to use Marionette, as it's enabled by default.**

*To use Marionette in your tests you will need to update your desired capabilities to use it.*

**Java** :

As exception is clearly saying you need to download latest `geckodriver.exe` from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and set downloaded `geckodriver.exe` path where it's exists in your computer as system property with with variable `webdriver.gecko.driver` before initiating marionette driver and launching firefox as below :-

```
//if you didn't update the Path system variable to add the full directory path to the executable as above mentioned then doing this directly through code
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/geckodriver.exe");

//Now you can Initialize marionette driver to launch firefox
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(capabilities);
```

And for `Selenium3` use as :-

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

[If you're still in trouble follow this link as well which would help you to solving your problem](http://qavalidation.com/2016/08/whats-new-in-selenium-3-0.html)

**.NET** :

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions());
```

**Python** :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

# Tell the Python bindings to use Marionette.
# This will not be necessary in the future,
# when Selenium will auto-detect what remote end
# it is talking to.
caps["marionette"] = True

# Path to Firefox DevEdition or Nightly.
# Firefox 47 (stable) is currently not supported,
# and may give you a suboptimal experience.
#
# On Mac OS you must point to the binary executable
# inside the application package, such as
# /Applications/FirefoxNightly.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
caps["binary"] = "/usr/bin/firefox"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
```

**Ruby** :

```
# Selenium 3 uses Marionette by default when firefox is specified
# Set Marionette in Selenium 2 by directly passing marionette: true
# You might need to specify an alternate path for the desired version of Firefox

Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path = "/path/to/firefox"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, marionette: true
```

**JavaScript (Node.js)** :

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const Capabilities = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/capabilities').Capabilities;

var capabilities = Capabilities.firefox();

// Tell the Node.js bindings to use Marionette.
// This will not be necessary in the future,
// when Selenium will auto-detect what remote end
// it is talking to.
capabilities.set('marionette', true);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).build();
```

**Using `RemoteWebDriver`**

If you want to use `RemoteWebDriver` in any language, this will allow you to use `Marionette` in `Selenium` Grid.

**Python**:

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

# Tell the Python bindings to use Marionette.
# This will not be necessary in the future,
# when Selenium will auto-detect what remote end
# it is talking to.
caps["marionette"] = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
```

**Ruby** :

```
# Selenium 3 uses Marionette by default when firefox is specified
# Set Marionette in Selenium 2 by using the Capabilities class
# You might need to specify an alternate path for the desired version of Firefox

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox marionette: true, firefox_binary: "/path/to/firefox"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, desired_capabilities: caps
```

**Java** :

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

// Tell the Java bindings to use Marionette.
// This will not be necessary in the future,
// when Selenium will auto-detect what remote end
// it is talking to.
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
```

**.NET**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();

// Tell the .NET bindings to use Marionette.
// This will not be necessary in the future,
// when Selenium will auto-detect what remote end
// it is talking to.
capabilities.SetCapability("marionette", true);

var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
```

Note : Just like the other drivers available to Selenium from other browser vendors, Mozilla has released now an executable that will run alongside the browser. Follow [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) for more details.

[You can download latest geckodriver executable to support latest firefox from here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Comment: Thanks you so much. This works just perfect. But just for information, what is this geckodriver all about?
I have been working with selenium for quite sometime and i didn't come across this before. But now i had just recently change my machine and got this error.

Comment: @Reema Just like the other drivers available to Selenium from other browser vendors, Mozilla has released now an executable that will run alongside the browser. Have alook for more details..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/IWebDriver

Comment: How to set path for geckodriver for all platforms? My Java app is built across different systems.

Comment: @Michal You need to set geckodriver location to your system PATH variable which valid for all platform...what is you OS??

Comment: I decided to find another library that rarely make breaking changes like this. Seriously, after I updated the firefox or library, usually it will not works anymore. Even worse, the latest `geckodriver.exe` for windows only available for 64-bit system. It's time to say good bye to Selenium.

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo Why is not works.. could you explain more??? Haw did you tried??

Comment: I'm really confused. "The Selenium client bindings will try to locate the geckodriver" Is WebDriver turning into Geckdriver? What's going on here?

Comment: @8protons Have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver/status...This geckodriver provides by Mozilla, .. geckodriver implements WebDriver So selenium clients bindings try to locate geckodriver to support automation on latest firefox

Comment: Its not working for me.I am using .net I added the directory of the driver in the path but still the same issue.I migrated to selenium 3.0.Is there anything else I need to update?

Comment: @swathi Could you share how did you add the directory of the the path??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur able to solve it by getting the v0.11.1 version of  gecko driver.. thank you :)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Can you suggest the python alternative in this case to set a default download location. `profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir','D:\Downloads')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)`

Comment: @SurabhilSergy [Have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251583/downloading-file-to-specified-location-with-selenium-and-python)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Thanks. I have seen this already. I was looking the marionette driver way for that?  [Similar question - looking for pythonic way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086011/how-to-set-a-specific-download-location-in-mozilla-marionette-web-driver)

Answer (score 25):

1. Download gecko driver from the seleniumhq website (Now it is on GitHub and you can download it from  [Here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)) .

   2. You will have a zip (or tar.gz) so extract it.
   3. After extraction you will have geckodriver.exe file (appropriate executable in linux).
   4. Create Folder in C: named SeleniumGecko (Or appropriate)
   5. Copy and Paste geckodriver.exe to SeleniumGecko
   6. Set the path for gecko driver as below

.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: i was missing the path of this driver and now its working fine

Answer (score 3):

Selenium WebDriver Java code:

Download Gecko Driver from  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases based on your platform. Extract it in a location by your choice. Write the following code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.lynda.com/Selenium-tutorials/Mastering-Selenium-Testing-Tools/521207-2.html");
```

Comment: Location may vary individual to individual. I extracted it on D drive

Answer (score 0):

Every Driver service in selenium calls the similar code(following is the firefox specific code) while creating the driver object

```
 @Override
 protected File findDefaultExecutable() {
      return findExecutable(
        "geckodriver", GECKO_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY,
        "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver",
        "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases");
    }
```

now for the driver that you want to use, you have to set the system property with the value of path to the driver executable.

for firefox GECKO_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY = "webdriver.gecko.driver" and this can be set before creating the driver object as below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./libs/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I must to set path in properties file, in many hours I find the way:

## application.properties file:

```
webdriver.gecko.driver="/lib/geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64/geckodriver.exe"
```

in java code:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName());
private FirefoxDriver driver;
private FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile;
private final String BASE_URL = "https://www.myweb.com/";
private static final String RESOURCE_NAME = "main/resources/application.properties"; // could also be a constant
private Properties properties;

public Login() {
    init();
}

private void init() {
    properties = new Properties();
    try(InputStream resourceStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_NAME)) {
        properties.load(resourceStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not open Config file");
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not open Config file", e);
    }
    // open incognito tab by default
    firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", true);
    // geckodriver driver path to run
    String gekoDriverPath = properties.getProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver");
    log.log(Level.INFO, gekoDriverPath);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + gekoDriverPath);
    log.log(Level.INFO, System.getProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver"));
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver").replace("\"", ""));
    if (driver == null) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### I use from selenium-java-3.141.59 in windows 10 and solved my problem with this code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\gecko\\geckodriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```