# capybara firefox 48 is giving error

Tags: selenium, firefox, capybara

Updated the firefox to version 48 but it give the following error. Any help how to solve it:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:90:in `connect_until_stable'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:55:in`block in launch'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:43:in `locked'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:51:in`launch'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:43:in `initialize'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in`new'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in `for'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in`for'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:13:in `browser'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:45:in`visit'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:232:in `visit'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in`block (2 levels) in '
>       from /Users/mesutgunes/scripts/capybara.rb:53
>       from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `'

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium

Comment: 45 and 47 is working but 48 is not working possible I can downgrade but I want to test in 48

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox v48 is not usable (in Capybara) without selenium-webdriver v3 and geckodriver.  There is a beta version of selenium-webdriver v3 but it is currently missing a number of critical features (can't read the current value of form element for instance) and isn't really ready for real testing use yet.  Downgrade to 47 for now.

Comment: is there document about it? selenium 2 is not supported after 48?

Comment: @MesutGüneş  Its documented in the issues for the selenium project on github, and the fact that firefox 48 no longer supports FirefoxDriver and now requires use of the marionette protocol.  There is some support for it in selenium 2.53 if you configure the driver to use the marionette protocol but it's even more broken than trying to use it with the 3 beta.  In the 3 beta the marionette protocol is default.