# Firefox not opening the specified URL when I run my webdriver program

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am new to automation with selenium and trying to run a basic program to launch Firefox and open Google.com. But I get Firefox launched with "*about:blank&utm_content=firstrun*" Please help. Am on Windows 10 and Firefox version is: 48.0 (latest). I have the latest Selenium drivers and JRE versions too.

Here is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class GoogleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium/38676858#38676858

Comment: If you are using latest versions, then you have to user geckodriver to launch firefox browser. Check this Selenium 3 Example https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3

Comment: I tried the solution provided and changed my code as below, but still am getting the same issue:                                                                                         
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class GoogleTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/Users/gangamai/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64/geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");
 }

}