# why python selenium does not fill URL

Tags: python, selenium, url

My python code uses selenium to launche a firefox session, input a URL, and open the web page. It ran successfully until one day it stopped working. Firefox can be launched, but the URL is not filled in the url box. Hence the web page cannot be open for sure. It finally ends with a timeout error.

I updated/re-installed python and selenium and firefox. But the problem is not resolved. What causes this issue?

I cannot publish my work code here. Here is a piece of code that should work. Firefox is launched, but the URL is not input.

Thanks for hints.

from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')

Comment: I think your firefox browser updated with new version, and Mozilla has launched geckodriver to support latest firefox version with selenium, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium/38676858#38676858

Comment: Thanks for the response.Add the directory containing the executable to the system path? Does this mean to add the directory of the selenium folder to PATH envir variable? I did not find any file of geckodriver in the Python folder.

Comment: There is mention a link to download geckodriver and put this path to system variable

Comment: Download the latest executable geckodriver from here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: I do not have the permission to change the environment $PATH. However, a lower version of firefox can resolve the problem. Thanks Gaur.