# Selenium Webdriver 3- URL is not getting entered into the Firefox Browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Windows 10 - 32 bit

Selenium Version:

3.0.0 beta 3
 Browser:

Firefox 48.02
 Eclipse Luna 32 bit

```
 package newpackage;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
           System.setProperty "webdriver.firefox.marionette","D:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
      //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");


      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com";
    String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
    String actualTitle = "";

    // launch Firefox and direct it to the Base URL
    driver.get(baseUrl);

    // get the actual value of the title
    actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

    /*
     * compare the actual title of the page witht the expected one and print
     * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
     */
    if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
        System.out.println("Test Passed!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Test Failed");
    }

    //close Firefox
    driver.close();

    // exit the program explicitly
    System.exit(0);
}


}
```

Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   les":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"1.5","maxVersion":"9.9"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0,"seen":true}

Comment: looks like your selenium and firefox version are not compatible to each other. Try to switch to an older version of firefox or downgrade your selenium version to a stable version (v2.52.0)

Comment: Why are you commented this line `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");`?

Comment: Have a look [at this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium/38676858#38676858) to launch firefox using geckodriver..

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issues are coming in selenium 3.0 beta version.

If you are using using Selenium Standalone jar then you have to pass marionette as capabilities and initialize FirefoxDriver as follows:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Tried with geckodriver v 0.10.0.

```
String driverPath = "<path to gecko driver executable>";
public WebDriver driver;
public void launchBrowser() {
        System.out.println("launching firefox browser"); 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath+"geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
```