# Python selenium web driver error

Tags: python, selenium

It seems that loading the profile keeps failing even though I am specifying the path location of the profile it seems to be loading from a different path (according to the traceback). Am I missing something here?

**CODE**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

profile = FirefoxProfile('/Users/path/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/9s60syvx.default')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
<snip>
```

**TRACKBACK**

```
File "/Users/path/Python/Projects/test/login.py", line 12, in <module>
  browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
  self.binary, timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
  self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
  self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 108, in _wait_until_connectable
  % (self.profile.path))

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /var/folders/dy/yl4zdm8n5j184hhfq_2j3bdh0000gn/T/tmpY3UPuy/webdriver-py-profilecopy If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Firefox Version = 48.0.2

selenium Version = 2.53.6

OS Version = OSX 10.11.6

Comment: I Think this the compatibility issue between `selenium` and `Firefox`, you should try using `geckodriver`, follow [this link for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium)

Comment: I have attempted to use the geckodriver (aka wires) however I may not be doing it correctly. I will make another attempt and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I get `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'wires' executable needs to be in PATH.` Even though I have added the path to `PATH$`. I have renamed the binary to 'wires'. I have pointed the caps binary to the newly downloaded gecko (aka wires).

Comment: Yes, now its better, you need to put `geckodriver` executable location into System `PATH` variable before running it..:)

Comment: yes as mentioned I have already done that, still get the error

Comment: Follow this link https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/90

Comment: `firefox_capabilities['binary']` points to the `firefox` binary itself, not `geckodriver`.
Instead, add the directory where `geckodriver` lives to your path:
`os.environ["PATH"] += "path/to/geckodriver"`..

Comment: I added the dir to PATH directly via `sudo nano /etc/paths` as it was not persistent via `export`  but still get the error (I having been following https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver, again I did all of this already before making this post) Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Are you mention executable as well with the path??

Comment: I can confirm it is in the path using `wires` on the term command line, it runs as expected. Ill attempt to add via python as you suggested and see what happens

Comment: Am doing `caps["marionette"] = True`
 `caps["binary"] = "~/Applications/Firefox.app"` `browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123160/discussion-between-inoob-and-saurabh-gaur).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to move the `geckodriver` binary to the directory you already have in the `PATH`:

```
mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin
```

If you want to have it at a different location, please note that the `PATH` has to point to the directory that contains the `geckodriver` and not to the binary itself. To add the the custom directory to the `PATH` you should do it in the code because you probably don't want to have it system wide.

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'path/to/dir/containing/geckodriver/'
```

After that, do the usual stuff you want.

```
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] = '/usr/bin/firefox'
profile = FirefoxProfile('/path/to/your/profile')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities
                            firefox_profile=profile)
```

Comment: thanks, however i moved to chromedriver in the end and it works perfectly. So I wont be testing your solution, however if it gets vote ups by other with the issue im happy to accept it.