# Python 3.5 selenium, trying to open web page, address is always invalid

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to learn selenium and running a simple program always give me an invalid address. The program runs successfully and a browser window open, but it does not go to the address and I instead get "the address isnt valid." I have selenium and firefox properly installed, as far as I know.

any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver 
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://youtube.com')
```

Comment: Are you using Firefox 48? What if you switch to 47?

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium/38676858#38676858

Comment: @alecxe downloaded firefox 47 and it works thanks!