# How to set geckodriver in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

While executing a project I am getting error. as below
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

I downloaded the application as well but not able to understand how to configure in Intellij so that I should not get this error .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail to Launch Mozilla with selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

```
def userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir").minus("workspace\\selenium-groovy");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", userDir+"/.m2/repository/webdriver/geckodriver/win64/0.11.1/geckodriver.exe")
```

Change to the correct path of your geckodriver binary. Works for me in IntelliJ Maven build and repository dependencies.