# Setting Relative path in intellij for gecko driver throws error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Placing geckodriver in resources and mapping it works on the machine am working on, but not on any other machine. i need  it to export it to other machines, so that i am creating a jar which i need to run on any other machine, but when running the jar on other machine is throwing out "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property" error.

```
public static WebDriver createDriver() 
{
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./src/main/resources/geckodriver");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverProfile());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        return driver;

 [Please take a look at the image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/khGBu.png
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Java - The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/selenium-using-java-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdr)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're missing the file extension.
The following works for me using relative file paths:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", ".\\WebDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Edit: Have you tried to swap the order of these two lines? 
Unless I'm mistaken, the system property should be set prior to the creation of the WebDriver.

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./src/main/resources/geckodriver");
```

Should be

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./src/main/resources/geckodriver");
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Edited answer. Please try that.

Comment: This works when running from the ide ie intellij, but not from an executable jar.. firefox launches but wont load the url.

Comment: That's more than likely a separate issue. If Firefox is launching from the executable jar then your path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like:-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", new File("./src/main/resources/geckodriver").getCanonicalPath());
```

Comment: This works when running from the ide ie intellij, but not from an executable jar..