# Error in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Now, I am started to learn Selenium WebDriver.I have got the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver
>   system property; for more information, see
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be
>   downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Provide more info: 1. What are your exact testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? Provide error stack trace.

Comment: Did you google the error? What did you find? What have you tried to resolve the issue on your own?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/selenium-using-java-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdr

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using latest version of selenium. Unlike older versions, wherein you don't need to set system property for browser driver executable in case of firefox, the System.setProperty("path to geckodriver.exe") is required to be mentioned in code.
This should resolve your issue