# i am getting exception while starting coding

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:750)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at test_cases.Login_procedure.main(Login_procedure.java:10)
```

Comment: Did you google the error message? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/selenium-using-java-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this steps:

1. Download gecko driver from GitHub.
2. It will be in form of zip file.
3. Extract the file and place as per your convenience.
4. Now in code use setProperty(String key, String path) method to set the browser.