# How to set Selenium webdriver.gecko.driver setting in C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Straight out of the box I can't get selenium grid to work.  I have selenium server 3.4.0 and the following code produces the error shown

**Error received**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: The path to the driver executable must be set by the 
webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded 
from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
```

**Simple code**

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = new Uri("http://10.6.122.49:5555/wd/hub");

            var options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.SetPreference("webdriver.gecko.driver", @"D:\geckodriver.exe");

            var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, options.ToCapabilities());

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Java - The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/selenium-using-java-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdr)

Answer (score 2):

I have explained here with clear example, make your changes accordingly

**NOTE**: Make sure of following this before starting.

1. If you are using GeckoDriver v0.19.0 use Firefox version 55.0 (and greater) and Selenium 3.5 (and greater)
   Also make sure to download the right version of GeckoDriver e.g. windows 32 or windows 64 bit for your operating system.

You can download Geckodriver from this location 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;


namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {

        FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"D:\dev1"); // location of the geckodriver.exe file

        [Test]
        public void GeckoDriverImplementation()
        {

            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an environment variable with the name : webdriver.gecko.driver and value =D:\geckodriver.exe under the system variables. and you can safely remove

```
options.SetPreference("webdriver.gecko.driver", @"D:\geckodriver.exe");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: See my update, after making this change I get the error shown in the screen shot

Comment: you did not remove options.SetPreference("webdriver.gecko.driver", @"D:\geckodriver.exe");? try and remove it please

Answer (score 0):

in C#

```cs
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.gecko.driver", @"C:\full\path\to\geckodriver.exe");
```