# Selenium testing is throwing webdriver exception

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

We are carrying out selenium tests in windows Machine from Jenkins. I have added the ChromeDriver 2.36 under C:\Selenium\path. My Selenium_Server_standalone_2.53.0.jar is placed under C:\Selenium. Chrome Browser Version is 65. While executing the test am seeing issue with Chromedriver path not being set properly.

```
**Path being added in config file :** ChromeDriver=C:/Selenium/path/SeleniumChromeDriver.exe

**Path being set in source code**:
String strChromeDriverPath = strConfigValues[18];
            File fileChromeDriver = new File(strChromeDriverPath);
            System.out.println("Chrome Driver Path: "+ fileChromeDriver.getAbsolutePath());
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",fileChromeDriver.getAbsolutePath());

**Logs:**

01:49:43    [testng] Chrome Driver Path: C:\Selenium\path\SeleniumChromeDriver.exe
01:49:43    [testng] Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 5553
01:49:43    [testng] Only local connections are allowed.
01:49:45    [testng] org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
01:49:45    [testng] Command duration or timeout: 17 milliseconds
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing within `String strChromeDriverPath = strConfigValues[18];`?

Comment: @DebanjanB getting string from string array probably and i guess it is this one C:/Selenium/path/SeleniumChromeDriver.exe

Comment: I recommend testing with latest chrome driver, also try setting string to C:\\Selenium\\path\\SeleniumChromeDriver.exe

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/selenium-using-java-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdr

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing says it all :

```
01:49:43    [testng] Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 5553
01:49:43    [testng] Only local connections are allowed.
01:49:45    [testng] org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

The log messages clearly says that *ChromeDriver 2.36.540470* was detected and a *Browsing Session* was initiated successfully to open the *Browser Client*.

But in the next step when the *Browser Client* tried to communicate back to the *Driver Server* i.e. *ChromeDriver*, the communication failed as the path of *ChromeDriver* initially known by *JVM* i.e. **C:/Selenium/path/SeleniumChromeDriver.exe** might have got changed through the **Jenkins Configuration**. As the *Browser Client* fails to communicate with the *ChromeDriver* at the previously known location and doesn't finds it a *WebDriverException* is raised as follows :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;
```