# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities while initiating Firefox v37 through Selenium v3.11.0

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to run test a run a website in Firefox, but I am getting error "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;" I have set the path correctly, still don't know where the problem is. Here is my code:

```
if (browsers.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) 
{
        String driverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src/test/java\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "false");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } else if (browsers.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
        // String driverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
        // "\\src\\Drivers\\chromedriver";
        // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
```

Here is the Failure Trace of my code:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass launchBrowser
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.8.0', revision: '924c4067df', time: '2017-11-30T11:36:59.109Z'
System info: host: 'DSCHD-PC-180', ip: '192.168.6.122', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at Utility.UtilityMethods.openBrowser(UtilityMethods.java:26)
    at TestCases.LoginTestCase.launchBrowser(LoginTestCase.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:455)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass quitBrowser
SKIPPED: registration
```

Comment: This is a potential duplicate issue. Please see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/selenium-using-java-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep things simple, as you are using *Selenium Client v3.11.0* and *Firefox v37* you need to download the latest *GeckoDriver* from [**mozilla/geckodriver**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and save it any where within your system. Next within the `System.setProperty()` line pass the *Key* **webdriver.gecko.driver** along with the *Value* as the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* and finally through *DesiredCapabilities* class set the capability **marionatte** to **false** and merge into an instance of *FirefoxOptions* instance to initiate the *Firefox* browser as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/path/to/geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability("marionatte", false);
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.merge(dc);
FirefoxDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
System.out.println("Application opened");
System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

---

### Update

As per your comment update you are using **GeckoDriver v0.20.1**.

But if you look back at the Release Notes of **GeckoDriver v0.18.0** it clearly mentions :

```
geckodriver now recommends Firefox 53 and greater
```

So using **GeckoDriver v0.18.0** and above you have to mandatory use Firefox 53 and greater. To get rid of this constraint you can downgrade either to any of these versions :

- **GeckoDriver v0.17.0**
- **GeckoDriver v0.16.1**

Comment: This code is giving me error " Unable to find a matching set of capabilities", That mean it did not have set the capability marionatte to "false"

Comment: Just to update you , I have done some changes- dc.setCapability("marionatte", false);
   
   FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);  ....This have initiated the Firefox browser but now I am getting the error "connection refused", Why is this happening?

Comment: @RohnKerry Update the question with the complete error stack trace for further analysis please

Comment: I have edited and added the error stack trace of my code.

Comment: I have found the solution for that. The code is : System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","D:\\geckodriver.exe");

Comment: Wait, that's **not** the right solution, gimme some time to get back to you. Update me your **GeckoDriver** please.

Comment: My geckodriver version is- geckodriver-v0.20.1

Comment: the solution I pasted in comments is working fine for me, So I guess it is the right solution.

Comment: @RohnKerry Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Answer (score 1):

This is how system property is set:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\...\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error for 2 days, the solution for me was in Set.Platform, put Platform.ANY or Platform.Windows because Platform.WIN10 not worked, marionette wasn't necessary.

```
public class Main { public static RemoteWebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/Lib/geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new 
                                        DesiredCapabilities().firefox();
    desiredCapabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
    desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.20.19.182:5557/wd/hub"), 
                                                desiredCapabilities);
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
    driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys("execute automation");
    driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    driver.close();
    // write your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using **user.dir** that basically means : current working directory

Here is the code that let you initialize firefox browser using selenium.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your\\gecko\\driver\\path\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new firefoxDriver();
```

That's it ! you can use Firefox driver to performs several operations like :

```
1.  driver.get(String args0);
2.  driver.getCurrentUrl();
3.  driver.getPageSource();
4.  driver.getTitle();
5.  driver.findElememt(By args0);
6.  driver.findElements(By args0);
7.  driver.naviagate();
8.  driver.manage();
9.  driver.close();
10. driver.quit();
11. driver.switchTo();
12. driver.getWindowHandle();
13. driver.getWindowHandles();
```

Please let me know if you have any concerns related to this.

Comment: That is correct but the issue is, I am using firefox version 37, So I have to put marionette= false. Now we can send only two string values in .setProperty.So where I can put the path to the geckodriver?

Comment: Which version of selenium you are using with FF37?

Comment: Like can we do that- System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette=false", "driverPath");  ?

Comment: I am using selenium 3.11.0

Comment: @RohnKerry : I'm not sure about this. Give me some time, if I will find anything, I will update you !

Comment: Sure  cruisepandey, I appreciate your help and efforts to help me resolve my issue.

Comment: No issue @RohnKerry. Cheers !

Comment: @RohnKerry why don't you try adding set property twice? One for marinette and other for driver path

Comment: Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Just updated your code. You will have to set driver path while `setProperty` and user `webdriver.gecko.driver` for latest firefox driver.

```
    if (browsers.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
            String driverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe"; 
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "driverPath"); 
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false); 
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(); 
            options.merge(capabilities);
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } 
        else if (browsers.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
            // String driverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
            // "\\src\\Drivers\\chromedriver";
            // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
```

Let me know.

Comment: But the problem is I am not using latest firefox version, I am using ff version 37. That is why I have set the marionette= false, for compatibility.

Comment: @RohnKerry, the latest Firefox version is 59 and you don't need to set marionette for that if you are using ff version 37 then you have to use compatible `firefoxdriver.exe`

Comment: So you mean to say that I have to download a compatible Firefox Webdriver for ff version 37?

Comment: No need to download. you can use latest FireFox geckodriver and you can set marionette=false using _DesiredCapabilities_ class.

Comment: Yes I have already did that but the problem is you can pass two values to the .setProperty() and I have to also give path to geckodriver in that.

Comment: I have also  tried the code : String driverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "D:\\Workspace\\YourLogo\\src\\test\\java\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe";
   System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "driverPath");
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: @RohnKerry, Please look my updated answer. Added DesiredCapabilities and FirefoxOptions.

Comment: May I know what is this for?- FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(); 
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);