# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused while launching Firefox Browser 45.0.1 through Selenium v3.4.0 and geckodriver-v0.20.1

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm unable to launch Firefox browser for the following scripts.

**Script #1:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\selenium\\Geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);  
driver.close();
```

**Script #2:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\selenium\\Geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

My Firefox Version : 45.0.1 
Selenium Jar Version : selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0 
Gecko Driver Version : geckodriver-v0.20.1-win32

I'm getting the error message as mentioned below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'SYNCGDC4098', ip: '172.26.59.52', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:368)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    at seleniumtips.BasicScript.openApp(BasicScript.java:10)
    at seleniumtips.BasicScript.main(BasicScript.java:18)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the [geckodriver releases](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), the current latest version of the geckodriver is v0.20.1. You should use this one with the current latest version of the Firefox browser.

In addition, you are using an old version of selenium (from [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), the current latest one is the 3.12.0).

You need to update your firefox browser and the selenium standalone server.

If you want (are forced) to use the oldest one (45.0.1), you should use the related geckodriver.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the **Selenium** and **geckodriver** respectively as told by @Davide Patti. However in your **script1** this line :  `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);`  will not be supported by `Selenium 3.12.0` since it' been deprecated.

Code that you can try out :

```
FirefoxOptions foptions =  new FirefoxOptions();  
foptions.setCapability("marionette", true);  
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(foptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

...implies that [**WebDriverException**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverException.html) was raised as the driver failed to start its internal server to communicate with the *Java Client*.

To keep things simple, as you are using **Selenium Java Client v3.4.0** and **Firefox v45.0.1** you need to use compatible **GeckoDriver** binary.

- Release Notes of [**Selenium Java Client v3.4.0**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-3.4.0) mentions:

> Geckodriver 0.16 is strongly recommended

- So you have to bump down `GeckoDriver` binary version to **0.16.0**.
- Now as you would be using **Selenium Java Client v3.4.0**, **GeckoDriver v0.16.0** with **Firefox v45.0.1** you have to use the `System.setProperty()` line to pass the *Key* `webdriver.gecko.driver` along with the *Value* as the *absolute path of the GeckoDriver binary* and finally through an instance of [**DesiredCapabilities**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html) class set the capability **marionatte** to **false** and then use [**`merge()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) method from [**MutableCapabilities**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) class to merge the capability into an instance of [**FirefoxOptions**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html) instance to initiate the *Firefox Browser* as follows :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/path/to/geckodriver.exe");
  DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
  dc.setCapability("marionatte", false);
  FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
  opt.merge(dc);
  FirefoxDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
  driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
  System.out.println("Application opened");
  System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
  driver.quit();
  ```

You can find similar discussion in:

- [**org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities while initiating Firefox v37 through Selenium v3.11.0**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789963/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of/49791342#49791342)
- [**selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with Firefox 46 through Selenium**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782650/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a/47785513#47785513)