# Selenium 2.53 not working with FF 46

Tags: selenium

53 along with ff and not able to launch the url and getting the below error please help  , i have tried with many other ff browsers as well like 35,22,43 none of them worked:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
134481,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[{"locales":["en-US"],"name":"Security Protection","description":"Protect your surf the internet .And added a toolbarbutton to the customize ToolbarPaletteï¼Œ you can drag it to anywhere you like in the toolbar or addon bar .","creator":"lightning","homepageURL":null,"developers":["lipton"]}],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"4.0","maxVersion":"30.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0}
1531668488177   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"fftoolbar2014@etech.com","syncGUID":"C1mXOVu9V4sx","location":"winreg-app-global","version":"1.0.0.1025","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":"chrome://fftoolbar/skin/icon.png","icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"FF Toolbar","description":null,"creator":"roc","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":false,"userDisabled":true,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\1nzomf3v.default\\extensions\\fftoolbar2014@etech.com","installDate":1431851431102,"updateDate":1431851431102,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":24945,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.0","maxVersion":"99.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessComDeferredSave.addons.json  DEBUG   Write succeeded
```

Comment: Did browser open ? try to upgrade to FF 47.

Comment: Yes the browser is opening , tried with mozilla 47 as well still the issue persists., any other solution.

Comment: There was one bug back in 2016 , https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7819     ,can you upgrade selenium and FF version both along with driver ?

Comment: you want me to upgrade the ff and selenium to which versions?

Comment: @SameerGupta Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789963/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade your browser version and Selenium version to :

with respect to official docs :

```
Firefox 57 (and greater)
Selenium 3.11 (and greater)
```

in case you want to download gecko driver. That can be done [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)