# Unable to find a matching set of capabilities, python selenium in docker environment

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, desiredcapabilities

I'm getting Error in docker environment:
`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`.

Here's my config:

```
Python 3.9.0
selenium==3.141.0
webdriver-manager==3.2.2
pymongo==3.11.0
Mozilla Firefox 78.4.0esr
geckodriver 0.27.0
location for geckodriver:'usr/loca/bin'
```

My sample code for test:

```py
    from selenium import `webdriver` 
    from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
    opts = FirefoxOptions() 
    opts.add_argument("--headless") 
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts) 
    browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789963/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of

Comment: I think you want "-headless" there.

Answer (score 0):

I spent an hour on this and solved the problem by downgrading geckodriver to 0.26.0
There may be an issue with the latest release, I am not confident enough in my setup and/or ability to confirm this.